# Fetch data from table and display in combo box?

Tags: java, jdbc

Oracle Table::

```
create table Appointment(App_ID number primary key,
Doctor_ID number,
Patient_ID number,
App_Date Date,
App_Time TIMESTAMP,
App_Charges number);
```

I have this as  my GUI :2 buttons "insert","Display"

```
JComboBox combo_time, combo_charges;
JTextField text1, text2, text3, text4;
final String[] sTime = {
        "10:00", "10:15", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45", 
        "12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", "13:30", "13:45", 
        "14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", "15:15", "15:30", "15:45",   
};

final String[] sCharges = {
        "300", "500", "700", "900", "1100", "1300", "1500", 
};

for(int iCtr = 0; iCtr < sTime.length; iCtr++) {
    combo_time.addItem( sTime[iCtr] );
}

for(int iCtr = 0; iCtr < sCharges.length; iCtr++) {
    combo_charges.addItem( sCharges[iCtr] );
}
```

JDBC::

```
if(e.getSource()==display) {
    try {
        //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        //Connection      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Employee");
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Connection        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:xe", "hr", "hr");
        String            t1  = text1.getText();
        int               id  = Integer.parseInt(t1);
        PreparedStatement st  = con.prepareStatement("select * from appointment where App_ID=?");
        st.setInt(1,id);
        ResultSet         rs  = st.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            text1.setText(t1);
            text2.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(2)));
            text3.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(3)));
            text4.setText(rs.getString(4));     
            combo_time.addItem(rs.getString("App_Time"));
            combo_charges.addItem(rs.getInt("App_Charges"));
        }
    }
```

Now i can fetch the data from the table but i have one column as `Date` and one as `Timestamp`, I don't know how to fetch them and convert it to String and then display time in combobox(format `hh:mm` but in table it's `Timestamp`) and date in `TextField`.
Although i tried the above code, i am getting the data but combo box is showing the Default values i.e the first item in the combo box .What i want is to show the `App_Time` value in `combo_time` from table for corresponding `App_ID` and `App_Charges` value in `combo_charges`.
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

String text1 = myFormat.format(rs.getDate(index1));    
String text2 = myFormat.format(rs.getTimestamp(index2));
```

Comment: and how to set it for a textfield ? like this ?
 t4.setString(text1);
And for combo box?

Comment: i edited the code in my post go through it.
i'm getting the data but combo box is showing the Default values i.e the first item in the combo box .What i want is to show the "App_Time" value in combo_time from table for corresponding App_ID and App_Charges value in combo_charges

Comment: i did this
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy");

String text1 = myFormat.format(rs.getDate(index1)); 
text4.setText(text1);
But in textfield i'm getting the date as "09-00-14" while in my table it's "09-JAN-14"

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)? You'll have to pass "HH:mm" to the constructor, not "dd-mm-yy".

Comment: yeah!1 but that's for time.i did it for time it worked.but i want to display date in textfield in format dd-mm-yy ,and when i'm using "hh:mm" ,i'm getting time in my date textfield.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Can't you use 2 date formats with different patterns?